# Creating custom raster pyramid using ArcPy

Tags: raster, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, image-pyramids

I have an ArcPy script that runs the Point Density tool several times for the same extent, using the same number of neighborhood cells, but with cell size increasing at an multiple of 2 with each pass. The purpose of my point density rasters are purely data visualization, and I plan on publishing my point density visualization using ArcGIS Server 10.2.

The idea is to make the point density visualization more specific as you zoom in the map, e.g switching to point density raster of ever smaller cell sizes as you zoom deeper in, and the point density rasters become less generalized. This imposes a scale limit for each of my point density raster, much the same way as pyramid levels in a raster pyramid.

Is there a way I can build a custom raster pyramid and input my own point density rasters as the pyramid levels?

At the moment I have 7 scales for my rasters, meaning I would need 7 layers in my map service when really only one would be needed if I could generate my own pyramid.

I have tried to Google for Build pyramid tools and .ovr file management for arcpy, but so far I haven't found any solutions yet.

Comment: Could you acheive the same result by dragging all 7 rasters in to an MXD and setting the visable scale range of each raster so that only one was ever visable